# How to run Hardware Lab Kit Ndis 6.5 LWF Logo tests?

Tags: windows, driver

I have installed Hardware Lab Kit for Windows 10 1809. Studio and controller runs on Windows 2016 server and target machine is Windows 10 1809. I want to release product with Ndis 6.8 LWF driver and need to test it in above environment.
When I create project and select my driver then I see only: "Hypervisor code Integrity Test", and "TDI filters and LSPs are not allowed test", but no "NDIS 6.5 LWF Logo test"
I try to resolve this problem third week, I reinstalled machines with HKL, tried on different machines, the result is always the same.

What is wrong with my environment ?

Answer (score -1):

After weeks of experiments I have verified that HLK Manager is able to run this tests. But there are needed some manual changes in test details and target machine. HLKStudio probably does not support this test event documentation says that yes.

Comment: Can you please share your setup and what was necessary to run these tests? I'm stuck there too.